# what is the benefit of using api from other domain over direct ajax call to the same domain

Tags: php, web-services, api

For single page application, so many websites are using (Or wish to use) api for their application and generally api domain is set some differenet from current one.

for ex: if domain name is "domain.com"

then api domain name is "api.domain.com".

so for fetching data we call the api from the "domain.com", then it connect to "api.domain.com", then "api.domain.com" creates a DB connection and returns responses.

I think is will be fast if we just do it on "domain.com"., because first we established a connection with "api" then api communicate to Database.

So i want to understand why are using api is better way in order to performance of a web application.

Thanks

Comment: Separation of logic...

Comment: `example.com` and `api.example.com` are within the same domain, it is only separate host names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Splitting them across two hostnames allows them to be split across two computers. This can help with scaling.

It allows different web servers to be used (e.g. you might have a server optimised for serving up static file to serving up a SPA while the API that provides its data is written using Node.js or Servlets).

It allows cookies to be limited to one of the two systems (e.g. so the cookie that identifies a user to the API isn't sent in every request to load an image from the static server).

It limits the points where the two codebases have to touch, making it easier to develop them independently. (e.g. by two different teams or with consideration for the API to be used by a client other than the SPA).

Comment: Thanks  but if we consider response time / performance of application, then which will better to go with for SPA?.

Comment: Danger! Danger! Premature optimisation alert! Micro-optimisation alert! Danger! (It doesn't make enough difference to care about (especially in light of the other factors). Focus on the stuff that actually makes your app slow instead.)

Answer (score -1):

This helps in proper code managemment.
By creating an API, it can be used from a portal front-end, mobile devices and various services.

I also think it's easier to create services in the same domain for single page applications. However, if the project gets bigger, it is easier to handle things with an API.

Comment: The question is asking why the API is on a subdomain instead of the root domain. It isn't asking why the API exists in the first place.